# Questions about building a fence: Odd angles, staining timeline, depth of posts, order of hardscaping, and tips for gate

Tags: fence, post, gates

We live near the bay area in California and currently planning our front yard fence. I have already touched base with city about property line and possible height restrictions, so nothing needed there (unless there are common unknowns you'd like to share). Style = horizontal fence ( like this [example](https://www.southernwoodspecialties.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/20210328_083021.jpg) My Key questions surround the following. ( [pictures of my design and others](https://imgur.com/a/K2Gsj9Z) )

​

- **Order of operation -** In addition to building this fence we would like to add pavers, decomposed granite/sandy area, plant border inside fence, and future turf/grassy area. I was initially thinking we needed to do everything on the inside first but after speaking with some possible contractors months ago I was convinced that doing the fence first would be a good idea. All of the above projects are occurring in different areas ( you can see one of the pictures has a sort of plan for the future with grey = pavers, tan = sand'ish area, green= turf/grassy, brown = plant border) . We would be planning to have a large enough gate opening to get materials/vehicles in so thought it wouldn't be an issue. Thoughts on this?
- **Odd fence angles -** In the main plan picture you can see near the top left a fence that would be an obtuse angle. Whats the best way to build this correctly? We are planning a horizontal plank fence and so I thought we may need an additional post screwed onto the main post cut at the proper angle to give a face to screw the face of planks into it. Does that make sense, or is there another better approach? Pictures included to show what I mean here
- **Post setting depth/material -** with a 6ft high fence I believe we needed to bury post 2-3ft into ground (meaning a 10ft post would be ideal). Should I put gravel at bottom of hole, place in post, then pour in concrete? If this is optimal, would red lava rocks work for the gravel? We just found a lot burried underneath lots of vines that we can repurpose.
- **Building double wide gate -** Our gate plan (in pictures) is to have the full width opening split between 2 hinge gates allowing them both to swing. Should this open in towards house or away? Should I consider 4x6 or 6x6 posts here for additional strength? The fence near the gate would actually be about 4 ft high instead as we would step it down further down from where the gate starts. Can you lend any tips on how to properly build this? We were thinking of having one of the gates closed most of the time and a metal rod going into the ground to keep it steady/supported but removable to have larger opening.
- **Staining procedure -** Currently the weather has been dry but I'm assuming the rain will come soon. Would I be able to build this within the next couple weeks and be able to stain immediately after if no rain comes? I read/heard for a variety of sources that suggested waiting a while to stain and if the weather gets more wet I might have to wait till the late spring/summer to stain it properly. Would this mean the wood would greatly deteriorate during that time period?

We are doing this ourselves and so I'm trying to be as prepared as possible for the hiccups on the way so I would appreciate any tips as well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You've got a lot of questions here, and they're all good ones. Unfortunately, you have a lot of questions here... This site works on a one-question-per-question basis because I might give you a good answer to your first question, then someone else might give you a good answer to your last question, then which one do you click the check mark for? Please [edit] this down to one question, then feel free to hit the "ask question" button again for the next one. Nobody will look down on you for this and it will keep this one from getting closed.

Comment: Convert this to 5 separate questions. As each of those has a different answer/requires different expertise.

Comment: [Edit] this down to one, and make 4 new questions for the others.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!